# Convert forloop to list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert the following to list comprehension but struggling:

```
lorem_ipsum = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."""

def word_count2(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split() 

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts

print(word_count2(lorem_ipsum))
```

So far I have tried a few variations on this:-

```
aString = lorem_ipsum

counts = dict()
words = aString.split

[counts[word] += 1 if word in counts else counts[word] = 1 for word in words]
```

Unfortunately, it has been some hours now but nothing I have tried seems to work

Comment: Your function returns a `dict`. How do you expect to get one from a list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning! You are trying to use a side effect inside of a list comprehension:

```
[counts[word] += 1 if word in counts else counts[word] = 1 for word in words]
```

tries to update `counts` for every `word`. List comprehension are not meant to be used like that.

The class `itertools.Counter` is designed to solve your problem, and you can use a dict comprehension that counts every element (see other answers). But the dict comprehension has a O(n^2) complexity: for every element of the list, read the full list to find that element. If you want something functional, use a fold:

```
>>> lorem_ipsum = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."""
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda d, w: {**d, w: d.get(w, 0)+1}, lorem_ipsum.split(), {})
{'Lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'dolor': 1, 'sit': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'consectetur': 1, 'adipiscing': 1, 'elit.': 1}
```

For every word `w`, we udpate the current dictionary: `d[w]` is replaced by `d[w]+1` (or `0+1` if `w` was not in `d`).

That gives a hint on how you could have written your list comprehension:

```
>>> counts = {}
>>> [counts.update({word: counts.get(word, 0) + 1}) for word in lorem_ipsum.split()]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> counts
{'Lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'dolor': 1, 'sit': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'consectetur': 1, 'adipiscing': 1, 'elit.': 1}
```

As you see, `[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` is the real return value of the list comprehension. The dictionary `count` was updated but **do not do this!**. Do not use a list comprehension unless you use the result.

Comment: Thank you for the warning there. Given this and the tenor of the other answers here I will certainly try and avoid using comprehensions in this fashion going forward.

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, you don't even need any list/dict comprehensions.  Just use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(lorem_ipsum.split())
# >>> print(counts)
# Counter({'ipsum': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'sit': 1, 'elit.': 1, 'consectetur': 1, 'adipiscing': 1, 'dolor': 1, 'Lorem': 1})
```

If you *really* want to do it the old-fashioned way, you could do something like:

```
words = lorem_ipsum.split()
counts = { word: words.count(word) for word in words }
# >>> print(counts)
# {'ipsum': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'sit': 1, 'elit.': 1, 'consectetur': 1, 'adipiscing': 1, 'dolor': 1, 'Lorem': 1}
```

Also, don't use `str` as a variable name.  It shadows the built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str) function, which makes that function unusable and can lead to hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: It seems that using the collections.Counter is the better solution so thanks for that advice. Unfortunately, I have a specific request to use the 'old-fashioned' approach so have used your comprehensions version which works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I will also avoid str as a variable name - again thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3):

Comprehensions aren't the right tool for this job. A `collections.Counter` is:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(lorem_ipsum.split())
>>> print(counts)
Counter({'Lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'dolor': 1, 'sit': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'consectetur': 1, 'adipiscing': 1, 'elit.': 1})
>>> counts['Lorem']
1
>>> counts['foo']
0
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am required to use the 'wrong tool' but point taken. I will try and use your much better approach when free to do so :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're really asking for is a dictionary comprehension, not a list comprehension. They're similar, but the syntax is a little different

```
# list comprehension
[foo for foo in stuff]

# dict comprehension
{key: val for key, val in some_tuple}
```

The trouble is, this won't work for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comprehensions work as either `map`, where they make a new collection with each element transformed somehow, or a `filter`, where there is a new collection with some elements possibly removed. These are stateless operations.

Word counting involves keeping track of things you've already seen. This is a `reduce` operation, where you keep the state in some other data structure, `counts` in your case.

As other answers have said, `collections.Counter` is the "right" way to solve this problem.

With all that said, here's how to use a list comprehension to count words. Please don't try this at home (or at work...especially not at work...)

```
>>> lorem_ipsum = """
... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
... """ * 2
>>> result = {}
>>> words = lorem_ipsum.split()
>>> [result.update({word: result.get(word, 0) + 1}) for word in words]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> result
{'consectetur': 2, 'ipsum': 2, 'amet,': 2, 'adipiscing': 2, 'sit': 2, 'elit.': 2, 'dolor': 2, 'Lorem': 2}
```

This works because a comprehension is basically a for loop behind the scenes, but you're still updating the state variable and just ignoring the actual list that gets created. In this case, it trades increased memory usage for readability, not a great choice.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution there, very helpful. It looks like I need to do some reading-up on list vs dict comprehensions (as well as collections). This is an excellent pointer

Answer (score 1):

You can use count for this.

```
lorem_ipsum = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
"""

word = {word:lorem_ipsum.split().count(word) for word in lorem_ipsum.split()}
print word
```

Comment: I fixed the answer.