# List of tuples to dictionary with duplicates keys via list comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of tuples with duplicates and I've converted them to a dictionary using this code I found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61201134/2415706

```
mylist = [(a,1),(a,2),(b,3)]    
result = {}
for i in mylist:  
   result.setdefault(i[0],[]).append(i[1])
print(result)
>>> result = {a:[1,2], b:[3]}
```

I recall learning that most for loops can be re-written as comprehensions so I wanted to practice but I've failed for the past hour to make one work.

I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56011919/2415706 and now I haven't been able to find another library that does this but I'm also not sure if this comprehension I want to write is a bad idea since append mutates things.

Comment: There's no direct equivalent, because `result` doesn't exist while you are using a dict comprehension. Trivially, you can do the unecessarily inefficient: `{k:[y for x,y in mylist if x==k] for k,_ in mylist}`

Comment: Note, "I recall learning that most for loops can be re-written as comprehensions" Just simply isn't true, and even if it were the case, most loops should **not** be re-written as comprehensions. Comprehensions are declarative constructs for expressing mapping/filtering operations on arbitrary iterables to yield some container (list, dict, set...). For-loops are imperative constructs and are the basic control-flow construct in Python. Not really equivalent at all, when it comes to use-case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comprehension is meant to map items in a sequence independent of each other, and is not suitable for aggregations such as the case in your question, where the sub-list an item appends to depends on a sub-list that a previous item appends to.

You can produce the desired output with a nested comprehension if you must, but it would turn what would've been solved in *O(n)* time complexity with a loop into one that takes *O(n ^ 2)* instead:

```
{k: [v for s, v in mylist if s == k] for k, _ in mylist}
```

Comment: Very educational, thank you. That time complexity seems not worth it, I'll keep it as it was.